# Scipy odeint outputs incorrect solution for coupled ODE's

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of three ODE's. At this point I am not sure if I set up my equations wrong or if it is a code problem.

I am trying to analyze a pendulum, with sliding point masses attached, as shown in this image: [image]

My free-body diagram and equations: [image]

My code:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pendulum
b1=2
g=9.81

#mass 1
m1=5
k1=10
b2=0
R1=5

#mass 2
m2=4
k12=9
b3=0
R2=10

#Initial conditions
r1_0=5
v_r_1_0=0

r2_0=12
v_r_2_0=0

theta_0=0
omega_0=0

S_0=[r1_0,v_r_1_0,r2_0,v_r_2_0,theta_0,omega_0]

#DiffEq function
def dSdt(t,S):
    r1,r1dot,r2,r2dot,theta,thetadot=S
    return [r1dot,
            (-k1*(r1-R1)-b2*r1dot-k12*(r1-R1-(r2-R2))+m1*g*np.cos(theta))/m1,
            r2dot,
            (-k12*(r1-R1-(r2-R2))-b3*r2dot+m2*g*np.cos(theta))/m2,
            thetadot,
            (-thetadot*b1-m1*g*(r1)*np.sin(theta)-m2*g*(r2)*np.sin(theta))/(m1*(r1**2)+m2*(r2**2))
           ]
#Solve
t=np.linspace(0,10,20)
sol=sp.integrate.odeint(dSdt,y0=S_0,t=t,tfirst=True)

r1_vals=sol.T[0]
r2_vals=sol.T[2]
theta_vals=sol.T[4]

plt.plot(t,sol.T[0])
```

Here is a picture of the plot for R1(t): [image]

I've been struggling with this for hours now. How do I get the solution to not diverge to infinity? Is odeint not capable of the nonlinear equations?

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like you are calling `odeint` appropriately, but I haven't checked the equations themselves. `odeint` is capable of solving nonlinear ODEs, and I doubt that it is at fault here, but if you want to get a second opinion, try converting your code to use `solve_ivp` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), which is recommended for new code. The signatures are very similar. Do different values of `method` give you similar answers?

Comment: Is `r2` measured off of `r1`? If they are independent then I don't think the force from the second spring will have both 1 and 2 terms.

Comment: Or maybe the displacement length of the second spring is `(r2 - r1) - R2`.

Comment: I had the equations wrong. The derivations to the ODE's are in my answer. Also included are the plots.

Answer (score 0):

The correct equations of motion for the two-mass pendulum are shown in this image: [image]

The code that solves the system of ODE's:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython.display import display, clear_output,HTML


#pendulum
b1=100
g=9.81

#mass 1
m1=5
k1=10
b2=1

#mass 2
m2=4
k12=4
b3=0.5

#Initial conditions
r1_0=((m1+m2)*g/k1)+0
v_r_1_0=0

r2_0=((m2*g/k12)+r1_0)+5
v_r_2_0=0

theta_0=np.pi/3
omega_0=0

S_0=[r1_0,v_r_1_0,r2_0,v_r_2_0,theta_0,omega_0]

#DiffEq function
def dSdt(t,S):
    r1,r1dot,r2,r2dot,theta,thetadot=S
    return [r1dot,
            (-k1*(r1)-b2*r1dot-k12*(r1-r2)+m1*g*np.cos(theta))/m1,
            r2dot,
            (k12*(r1-r2)-b3*r2dot+m2*g*np.cos(theta))/m2,
            thetadot,
            (-thetadot*b1-m1*g*(r1)*np.sin(theta)-m2*g*(r2)*np.sin(theta))/(m1*(r1**2)+m2*(r2**2))
           ]
#Solve
t=np.linspace(0,60,400)
sol=sp.integrate.odeint(dSdt,y0=S_0,t=t,tfirst=True)
sol2=sp.integrate.solve_ivp(dSdt,t_span=(0,max(t)),y0=S_0,t_eval=t)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Mass Positions')
axs[0].set_ylim(0,30)
axs[0].plot(t, sol2.y[0],label='r1 [m]')
axs[0].plot(t, sol2.y[2],label='r2 [m]')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time [sec]')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Distance from pivot [m]')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Theta [deg]')
axs[0].invert_yaxis()
axs[0].legend()

axs[1].plot(t,sol2.y[4]*(180/np.pi),label='theta [rad]')
```

The plot:

[image]

Comment: It's still not clear if `r2` is measured from the pivot or referenced from `r1`. You also have the equilibrium length for `R1` correct in the code but wrong in your handwritten portion (it should depend on both masses).

Comment: One way to verify your code is to check that nothing happens if your set `r1=R1`, `r2=R2`, and `theta=0`.